# return json from JsonConvert.SerializeXNode with proper type

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, json.net

```
var test = new
            {
                TestStr = "test",
                TestNumber = 123,
                TestDate = new DateTime(1986, 1, 13, 17, 50, 31),
                TestBool = true
            };

var xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test), "test");
```

This code return nice xml element:

```
<test>
  <TestDate>1986-01-13T14:50:31Z</TestDate>
  <TestBool>true</TestBool>
  <TestNumber>123</TestNumber>
  <TestStr>test</TestStr>
</test>
```

When I try **convert this xml back to JSON**:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xml, Formatting.None, true);
```

I get JSON only with `String` properties.

What should I do to get json with proper types?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json.NET, can SerializeXmlNode be extended to detect numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770871/json-net-can-serializexmlnode-be-extended-to-detect-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

JSON and XML are different serialization formats, and have different capabilities.  JSON can differentiate between `string`, `number`, and `boolean` whereas XML treats everything as a string.  Therefore, when you convert from JSON to XML and back, the type information gets lost.  One way to handle this is to use an strongly-typed intermediate model when converting back and forth.  In other words, instead of converting directly from XML to JSON, deserialize your XML to the model, then serialize the model to JSON.  The model will force the data to be the correct types.

Here's an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"
        <test>
          <TestDate>1986-01-13T14:50:31Z</TestDate>
          <TestBool>true</TestBool>
          <TestNumber>123</TestNumber>
          <TestStr>test</TestStr>
        </test>";

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
        Test test = (Test)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}

[XmlType("test")]
public class Test
{
    public string TestStr { get; set; }
    public int TestNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }
    public bool TestBool { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "TestStr": "test",
  "TestNumber": 123,
  "TestDate": "1986-01-13T14:50:31Z",
  "TestBool": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like your answer, but "dynamic" is the key.I haven't info about Types.

Comment: If you have no info about the types then the best you can do is write custom code to try to guess the type based on the data value.  However, this is problematic because you could run into a case where a value is numeric but you still want it to be treated a string.  A good example is U.S. postal codes, which in some cases have a leading zero.  Automatically converting the string to int would drop the leading zero and change the value.  This is why Json.Net does not automatically try to guess types when converting from XML to JSON.